# Paste-once or paste-and-clear

Tags: password-management, unix, clipboard

I use a password manager (to be specific: [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/)) to store my passwords.  The interface I use most often is [passmenu](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/contrib/dmenu/passmenu) to put the password on my clipboard, which I can then paste in my terminal/browser/whatever.

Sometimes I'm not careful and I forgot that I have my password still on my clipboard and I paste it somewhere I shouldn't.  What I would like is to have some protection from myself and only be able to paste the password once:  after pasting the clipboard should be cleared.

Now it's probably not to hard to hack something together that does this with the standard unix tools.  Before I do so, I would like to know if I'm not reinventing something that already exists.  Also, it would be good to know if there are any password managers that have this functionality built-in?

Ps. I know that some password managers clear the clipboard after a specified *time*, but that's not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: write an autohotkey script that looks for a paste combo, waits one second, then runs a copy keypress

Comment: I'd just like to add that this _is_ a thing. I created a password manager and one of the features was that it cleared the clipboard when the shell closed. (https://github.com/libeclipse/visionary)

Comment: This sounds like the kind of question Ubuntu Stack Exchange would help with, except that you might not be using Ubuntu. Other then that I think Super User is a better fit than IT Security. Overall you might not be able to get good product recommendations from Stack Exchange because it is against their policy.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey: That seems reasonable. Is there a way I can move the question to Super User?

Answer (score 0):

I actually switched from pass to keepassx2, because it clears the clipboard after 5 seconds. Before that I just had a shell script, that I used to call pass that cleared, that clipboard 10 seconds after pass was closed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a password manager which provides this facility built-in. However, this is how I have implemented it in my system.

I use `gpaste` clipboard manager which can store multiple clipboard entries in a list. `gpaste` provides a command to delete a specified clipboard entry. Lastly, I have configured a hot-key `Ctrl + Super + V` to paste and delete the current entry.